How can you use gravity while trying to model gravity?
So consider the usual pop-science spacetime model, a bowling ball on a trampoline. Apparently, the ball should sink into the trampoline, causing a dip in the fabric which causes nearby objects to fall towards the ball, and so on and so forth. In this analogy the trampoline fabric is the fabric of spacetime and the attraction of other masses to the dip in the fabric is gravity.
However, this model requires that whatever mass is being considered as the gravity well is itself sinking into the fabric. How can something sink into the fabric when a) the fabric is 3 dimensional and b) there's no force of gravity to cause the ball to sink?

What's pulling the yellow ball into the fabric?

As the linked answers indicate, you should ignore the dip. Instead, look at how the sets of grid lines (which are parallel in flat spacetime) converge in curved spacetime.

It’s a prop. It not the actual model.

It's not a scientific model, it's an illustration where you can kind of get a partial intuitive understanding. One thing that this illustration gets wrong is that the fabric of the trampoline is really only analogous to space, not spacetime. Another is that the curvature is intrinsic, i.e., it doesn't dip into anything, but it has more to do with how regions of spacetime are interconnected to each other, coupled with how distances and angles are affected. Another one is that the objects are always moving through spacetime, by virtue of the passage of time.

Yes. This is exactly what ScienceClic said in their video. "You cannot explain gravity within spacetime by gravity "outside" spacetime." Spacetime is not embedded in anything else.

You don't need gravity, take an iron ball and place a magnet below the sheet. This is not an explanation but a visualization. it's supposed to show the expanding depths, which it does.
